# Is there a one-word adjective for "needs moderation"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When forum posts get flagged for some of the several reasons (offensive, copyright violation, etc.",) and are waiting for a moderator to look at them, they are [adjective].

I'm not looking for "offensive," I'm looking for something like "moderation-queued."

The word will be in a sentence describing a system behavior: "Given an offending post, it is marked as ..."

Comment: Would **flagged** itself not suffice in this situation? It by definition means "marked for attention or treatment in a specified way."

Comment: @Kangaroo_Lover that's an answer, expand it.

Comment: To expand on @Kangaroo_Lover's comment, i'd just say "flagged for moderation".

Comment: Imo, the notion of “needs moderation” used in your question’s title already goes too far beyond the neutral, single word that you need because it (as does “moderation-worthy”) implies that a determination regarding the comment’s “need for”(/“worthiness of”) REAL action (i.e., deletion, & not just review) by a moderator has already been made. Your “moderation-queued [as POSSIBLY worthy of mod action]” & my favorite, @Kangaroo_Lover 's “flagged [as POSSIBLY in need of mod action]” (as perhaps would "review-/attention-worthy") capture well the neutrality that, imo, you should be looking for.

Comment: Review-queued? Flagged is better.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with saying "it is marked as needing moderation". English does not have a morpheme that expresses a need. You cannot express "needs cake", "needs music", "need bubbles", or "needs moderation" in one word. You have to use two. That is the whole point of having a language. Combining simple words in simple ways to form complex thoughts. Why precisely do you not want to do that? Please explain. Oh, and while you're at it, do tell me how to say "needs cat" in one word.

Answer (score 0):

One word? Probably not.

A word which comes close (but does not receive a cigar) is *sanctioned*. To fit your purposes, I guess you'd need to add the word *possible* (or a variant of *possible*, or a word which indicates the possibility of such as sanction).

> A flagged post could possibly become a sanctioned post.

Or,

> A flagged post *may* become a sanctioned post.

Answer (score 0):

I use the word ***provocative*** for anything that will evoke differing amounts of acceptance or spark heated discussion. Often, under these circumstances a moderation of views is called for to allow some settlement of "issues."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [contentious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contentious)?

- likely to cause disagreement or argument
- exhibiting an often perverse and wearisome tendency to quarrels and disputes

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try *quarantine*d ([definition # 4 at MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quarantine)):

> a state of enforced isolation

I see it used in a similar sense [on reddit](https://reddit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205701245-Quarantined-Subreddits).

Answer (score 0):

When a post is flagged and awaiting moderation they are considered reported.

I would say flagged and reported would work for what you are looking for. Once moderation has occurred I would say the post has been actioned.